# Monitoring and managing zeromq applications

Tags: monitoring, zeromq

I am developing a distributed application with several small zeromq applications. is there a recommended way to monitor and configure all the zeromq applications? I think of configuring ports and network addresses, starting of applications, monitoring, etc. I know that there exist systems like Nagios, but I wonder if there is an easy and recommended way for zeromq.

Answer (score 0):

This is far from easy, because it depends on your system, its architecture and the requirements e.g. on availability that you have. If I assume that you provide a service that should be restarted when it becomes unavailable, there are a bunch of solutions:

- monit: http://mmonit.com/monit/
- runit: http://smarden.org/runit/
- daemontools
- some more alternatives: http://packages.debian.org/jessie/daemontools

None of these have as goal the configuration of services or their deployment. Also, independently monitoring instead of fully controlling your services is still a good idea, so keep your nagios install.

Comment: My architecture is Linux. Would you suggest to run the zeromq applications as daemons?

Comment: Your OS kernel is Linux, your architecture is probably x86 or AMD-64. Seriously, the architecture in question is that of the service that your zeromq app is supposed to provide and in which context. I'm just guessing you (yet unstated) requirements when I suggest creating something like a daemon.